# Firefox extension : toSource not working with Firebug.Console.log

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

On FF 4.0.1; and trying to develop my first FF extension.

Need to find where the user right clicked. From MDN it seems "gContextMenu.target" would have the information.

Trying to do the following and it doesn't show anything :

`let targetClicked = gContextMenu.target;

Firebug.Console.log("targetClicked : " + targetClicked.toSource());`

Nothing shows up, other .log statements are working correctly.

Wanted to use the Venkman JS Debugger, but its not compatible with 4.0.1.

Any ideas how to get that information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned that gContextMenu.target returns a DOM object, hence **.toString()** would work.

Note : The .target returns a DOM object wrapped in a XrayWrapper. Use `XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap()` to unwrap it before use.

oh yes, include this in your code so the object is available :
`<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://global/content/XPCNativeWrapper.js"/>`